# AdMob Banner appears 960x150 instead of 320x50 in libGdx - what's wrong here?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I am a bit helpless with this strange effect from AdMob.

AdView is instanciated in code and so is the relative layout and libGdx view.

```
        View view = initializeForView(Engine.createEngine(G.SPRITE_BATCH_SIZE, G.WORLD_SIZE_X, G.WORLD_SIZE_Y, MainMenuScreen.class,
        "backgrounds/loadingtransition.png", Engine.TRANSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT), config);

    relativeLayout.addView(view);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

    relativeLayout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(relativeLayout);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

First, I add the view from libGdx init, then I create the adView, centered on top.
The adSize is BANNER.

When I start the game, everything works as it should, a banner is displayed, but it's size is not 320x50, it is 950x150 with is exactly 3 times the width and height... That's way too big - I do not want that.

Can anyone help me out here, what I did wrong?
(It is my first AdMob experience, I am fairly new to all that stuff on Android)

[image: The ad says 320x50 but it is 960x150]

Answer (score 0):

use this two option:-

1) adView.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER);

2) adView.setAdSize(AdSize.LEADERBOARD);

Reference Documentation link [click here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#banner_size)

Comment: Those two are even larger. I think it has to do with the good old "dp" device pixel and screen pixel thing... I am using a SMART_BANNER now - this is way smaller.

Comment: Because SMART_BANNER and BANNER are use in regular size device not for large size device then you can use FULL_BANNER or LEADERBOARD also.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically load adsize based on the devices' screen resolutions:

```
AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;  
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();  
double density = dm.density * 160;
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);   
if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
    adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
} else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
    adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
} else { // > 320 X 50
    adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
}

adView.setAdSize(adSize);
```